# How to assign values to dynamic 2d array in C

Tags: arrays, 2d

I want to make a dynamic 2d array and to assign values and I cant understand my mistake.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void main () {

    int **a;
    int k;
    int nrows, ncols;
    int i, j, x;

    printf("Enter number of rows and columns: \n");
    scanf("%d%d",&nrows,&ncols);

    if( (nrows >=5 && nrows <=10) || (ncols >=5 && ncols <=10) )
    {
        if(nrows == ncols){
            a = (int **)malloc(nrows * sizeof(int *));
            if (a == NULL)
                exit(1);
        }else{
            printf("Rows must be equal to Columns\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }else{
        printf("Rows or Columns must be between 5 to 10\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i = 0 ;i < nrows ; i++) {
        *(a+i) = (int *)malloc(ncols * sizeof(int));
        if(*(a+i) == NULL) {
            for(k = 0; k < i; k++){
                free(a[k]);
                free(a);
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }


    printf("Write down your array:\n");

    for(i = 0 ; i < nrows; i++){

        *a =  *(a + i);
        for(j = 0; j < ncols; j++){

            scanf("%d", &x);
            *(*a + j) = x;
        }

    }


        printf("Your array is:\n");
       for(i = 0 ; i < nrows; i++){

        *a = *(a+i);
        for(j = 0; j < ncols; j++){

            printf("%d ", *(*a + j) );
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines

```
*a =  *(a + i);
```

are the problem: You are changing the first column pointer. You probably wanted to do here something like

```
int* tempColumnPointer = *(a + i);
```

Some tips:

1. `a[i]` would be better readable than `*(a + i)`
2. You can even use `a[i][j]` instead of `*(*(a + j) + i)`.
3. Why not allocate the matrix as one single memory chunk?